# Factoring a quadratic with number in front of $x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have not yet understood how to factor a quadratic that contains a number in front of $x^2$, without using the quadratic equation. I am used to just brute forcing numbers such that AB and A + B are solutions to it.

Example:

$7x^2 = 25x + 12$

....

$7x^2 - 25x - 12 = 0$

How steps do I need to take to proceed from here ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quadratic formula can help you find roots, from which you can find the equation's factors:

$$x_1, x_2 = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a} = \frac{25 \pm\sqrt{625-4(7)(-12)}}{2(7)} = \frac{25\pm 31}{14}$$

$x_1 = \dfrac{56}{14} = 4, \quad x_2 = \dfrac{-3}{7}$.

Hence, the equation factors as follows: $$7x^2 -25x - 12 = 0 \iff (x-4)(x+(3/7)) = 0 \iff (x-4)(7x+ 3) = 0$$

Comment: Wow, thanks for that insight. Ladies and gentlemen, please do abstain from answering this question any further because this man has won the accepted answer! (unless it so happens to be from the kindness of your hearts).

Comment: @amWhy To someone not familiar with factorising a quadratic expression with the coefficient of $x^2$ not equal to 1, I would not recommend using the quadratic formula (Also, this isn't a very efficient method), but it's nonetheless correct.

Comment: You're welcome, WeedWizard420!

Answer (score 3):

Since $7$ is prime, you know the factors will look like this:$$(7x+a)(x+b)$$
You also know the product of $a$ and $b$ is $-12$, so there are a few possible values.
As a hint, $-25$ is between $7*(-3)$ and $7*(-4)$.

Soon, you will learn about the general solution $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Method I:** Completing the square:

$$7x^2 - 25x - 12 
=7\left(x^2-\frac{25}7x-\frac{12}7\right)\\
=7\left(\left(x-\frac{25}{14}\right)^2-\left(\frac{12}7+\frac{25^2}{14^2}\right)\right)\\
=7\left(\left(x-\frac{25}{14}\right)^2-\left(\frac{961}{196}\right)\right)\\
=7\left(\left(x-\frac{25}{14}\right)^2-\left(\frac{31^2}{14^2}\right)\right)\\
=7\left(x-\frac{25}{14}-\frac{31}{14}\right)\left(x-\frac{25}{14}+\frac{31}{14}\right)\\
=7(x-4)\left(x+\frac{3}{7}\right)\\
=(x-4)(7x+3)\\
$$

---

**Method II:** Quadratic formula:

Using quadratic formula, roots are:
$$\frac{25\pm\sqrt{625+336}}{14}=\frac{25\pm31}{14}=4,\frac{-3}7$$
$$7x^2 - 25x - 12 = 0\equiv(x-4)\left(x+\frac37\right)=0$$
Now just multiply coefficient of $x^2$ as:
$$7(x-4)\left(x+\frac37\right)=0\equiv(x-4)(x+3)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have equation $\displaystyle 7x^2 - 25x - 12 = 0$ you can divide both sides by $7$ to get $\displaystyle x^2 - \frac{25x}{7}-\frac{12}{7}=0$. You can do the same in general case $ax^2+bx+c=0$ when $a \neq 0$.

Comment: Cool, seems great. So am I expected to find two numbers such that A + B = -25/7 and AB = -12/7 ?

Comment: @WeedWizard420 Yes. Precisely.